Need a method for managing systemd services across multiple hosts
I have six Linux servers running RHEL 8.6 - and need to ensure that one specific service is running at least one and at most one of those six servers.
Does systemd support something like this?
If not, is there an extension to systemd or another mechanism that provides the exactly-one-instance is running across a pool of servers?
The question here - systemd support for toggling mutually exclusive services? - starts to get at the question, but it still seems limited to services running on a single host.

i wouldn't think systemd would support this. It was designed after X Windows security holes were known. systemd is designed for managing the system it's on. OTOH, a couple of perl or python scripts (on the client: Listen (on a TCP/IP port) for authenticated commands (like 1, 2, etc. to trigger function 1 or 2, etc) and one on the master (to poll each client, sending cmds to do "is your service up?", "Start your service", "Stop your service", etc). Limit your command set to only what you need, beware feature creep. This requires programming.

systemd cannot manage services running on multiple hosts. You do have some other options.
Pacemaker + corosync
Pacemaker is a tool for managing resources across a cluster. It can do some of what you want, and pre-kubernetes it may have been one of the go-to tools for this sort of situation.  I find pacemaker to be one of the most sysadmin-hostile pieces of software out there and wouldn't personally recommend it.
Pacemaker does have native support for managing systemd services, which may be a vote in its favor. See e.g. this suse kb article.
This section of docs on clone resources may be relevant since you want to run multiple instances of a service.
Kubernetes
You could consider deploying a lightweight Kubernetes distribution like k3s on your hosts; then you can use Kubernetes constructs (like a Deployment) to set up multiple replicas of a service and use anti-affinity rules to ensure that those instances are spread out across your nodes.
Historical options
A long time ago, the CoreOS folks created fleet, which was a cluster-ized systemd, but that project was abandoned at least six years ago.
